# Real advantages of LaTeX over other formats

Tags: format-files, opmac

LaTeX has practically become the de facto standard in typesetting with TeX and has practically superseded all other formats (even to the point that some people consider TeX and LaTeX as synonims).  But, knowing also other formats such as OPmac or the old good LamSTeX, I can't understand what are the advantages of LaTeX over them.  Surely one advantage is that there are legions of people supplying additional packages on top of LaTeX to cope for practically any typesetting need.  But what if there were also legions of people writing extensions for the other two mentioned formats?  I think that they would be comparable (or, in my opinion, superior) to LaTeX.  I think the power of LaTeX resides not in LaTeX itself but in the added packages.  Am I wrong?  Could you explain what are the real advantages of the core-LaTeX over other formats?

Comment: You are right in surmising that LaTeX's widespread adoption (among users of *any* TeX format) is associated with the availability of useful packages meant to be used with LaTeX. It's important here to distinguish between between two rather distinct LaTeX formats: LaTeX209 and LaTeX2e. If my recollection is correct, it was really only after LaTeX2e was introduced (and more or less finalized) in 1994 that more and more users gravitated to LaTeX(2e). This switch, in turn, is explainable by the much-improved structure of LaTeX2e, which made it far more straightforward to write dedicated packages.

Comment: N.B.: OPmac is not a format.

Comment: @Henri Menke. But you can make it a format

Comment: Anybody is free to use other formats if he/she is not satisfied with `LaTeX`

Comment: @oettam [wipet himself calls](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html) it a macro package.

Comment: It is one of the core features of (core-)LaTeX that it encourages the writing of packages. It invites people.

Comment: Actually I disagree that those formats have many advantages over latex, but for most people most of the time, whether they do or not is irrelevant. The point of a language is to communicate with people so using the same language as other people is rather the point of the exercise. Using a system that no one uses and is not maintained by anyone (lamstex) or a system that is maintained but has essentially no users might be an interesting exercise but not something most people would want to do with a real document.

Comment: But this is clearly "opinion based" so I voted to close for that reason.

Comment: @HenriMenke Also LaTeX is a macro package, that happens to have been distilled into a format for faster loading.

Comment: @egreg I think the dividing line between format and macro package is whether the macros require `-initex`; the cleanest example of that is whether they require to process hyphenation patterns. But LuaTeX is already blurring that line. Thus, `hyplain` is a format, whereas `eplain` is a macro package.

Comment: @erreka I don't agree. Hyphenation patterns are a very special item that's not really specific to macro packages. It wouldn't be really difficult to have a “universal” format with all hyphenation patterns and to load `latex.ltx` at runtime.

Comment: @egreg that's what I mean: `latex.ltx` is meant to produce a format, since it requires to process hyphenation patterns, and thus *requires* `initex`; `opmac` on the other hand is a simple macro package, which may run on top of different formats. In this description, formats are a subset of macro packages; but of course, you can turn *any* macro package into a format with the magic word `\dump`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OPmac is macro package but OpTeX is the format (LuaTeX with OPmac). It is moderm Plain TeX. It keeps Plain TeX simplicity, it does not hide TeX. It is better than LaTeX, of course, because it does not solve the obscurities with old 8bit encodings and it does not need external programs for bibliography, syntax highlighting and Index sorting. The only problem is that there is only few users of OpTeX. But it may change. Will you help me with it?